# header files in C++

Tags: c++, file, header

In my C++ code, I want to include many header files that are placed in one folder. how can i include them all at once?

Comment: @ildjarn: that could very well be an answer.

Comment: Nine times out of ten, you don't need to include all of those headers in every file. Seriously reconsider whether this is actually necessary at the risk of increasing complexity.

Comment: isn't there a way to include the whole directory containing header files, in the code?

Comment: you can however automate the creation of the convenience header in your Makefile, see @edgar.holleis answer on that (but use better include guards)

Answer (score 11):

Create a header file that includes them all and include that instead.

I.e., I know of no compiler that has this functionality built in, and if one did it would certainly be non-standard functionality.

Comment: Since naming is the key: those "big" headers are generally called *convenience headers*. For example, you might see them in the **Boost** library, where generally a `optional.hpp` file will live right next to the `optional` folder and include (most of) its content.

Answer (score 4):

Execute the following shell commands in the directory which holds your .h files:

```
rm -f meta.h
echo "#ifndef META_H" >> meta.h
echo "#define META_H" >> meta.h
for h in `ls *.h`; do echo "#include \"$h\"" >> meta.h; done
echo "#endif /*META_H*/" >> meta.h
```

...and then #include "meta.h" alone.

Comment: your include guards are not recommended: C++0x draft standards §17.6.3.3.2 says `Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
global namespace.` The guards should not start with `_` or contain two `_`s.

Comment: @Mat : Specifically, two *consecutive* `_`s.

Comment: @ildjarn: indeed, that was not clear. The standards quote for that is: `Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.`

Comment: So this is a good bash solution so long as you remove the first underscore? Why not edit the solution to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You may wrap them in a helping header file. Having created it once, you can `include` it everywhere.